# CakePHP: allowing database update with button click

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have a product search page with the form below. The search result is displayed on the same page with search bar at the top.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Searches', array('action'=>'products', 'type' => 'get', 'name' => 'textbox1'));
echo $form->input($varName1, array('label' => false));
echo $form->end('Locate');
```

I also have a little box next to the search result that allows (it doesn't work yet) the user to flag using checkboxes a product and accordingly update its database (table `products` and using model `Product`) with a button click. Note that I have a `Searches` controller for this search page.

```
<form method="link" action="/myapp/product/test_update_db>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="flag1" <?php echo $preCheckBox1; ?>>Flag 1</input></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="flag2" <?php echo $preCheckBox2; ?>>Flag 2</input></label>                          
    <input type="submit" value="Update">                                
</form>
```

I'm having difficulty with this approach figuring out how to perform this check-box-and-DB-update routine. I'm getting to the link I'd like to go (`/myapp/product/test_update_db`), but I don't know how to take variables `flag1` and `flag2`, along with row ID of this result (`$results['Product']['id'])`) to the new page.

Could someone guide me on how to perform this neatly? Is this general approach correct? If not, what route should I be taking? I'd prefer not to use javascript at this time, if possible.

EDIT: I think I can make this work if I use the URL for passing data.. but I'd still like to know how this could be done "under the hood" or in MVC. I feel like I'm hacking at the CakePHP platform.

UPDATE: So, I ended up using the URL parameters for retrieving information pieces like `flag1` and `flag2`. I'm still looking for an alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using information embedded in the URL for getting submission data. Something like below..

In Products controller, when the form with `flag1` and `flag2` are submitted:

```
public function test_update_db() {      
    // Get variables from URL, if any, and save accordingly     
    $result = $this->Product->updateProduct($this->params['url'], 'url');
    if ($result) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully updated!', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Update was unsuccessful!', 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }       
}
```

This works for doing what I needed to do. I feel like there's a more proper way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

To see where your is-checkbox-checked data is located, do the following in your controller:

```
// Cake 2.0+
debug($this->request->data);

// previous versions
debug($this->data);
```

If you want to pass data to your search controller from the current page, you can always add the data to your form:

```
$this->input
    (
        'Product.id',
        array
        (
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'value' => $yourProductId
        )
    );
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. I'm trying to find out how to carry over the form submitted data (`flag1` and `flag2`) from the product search page to `product/test_update_db`. I'm already passing all data necessary from the controller (`Searches` controller) to the view (sesarch result page with checkbox form). I'm using CakePHP 1.3.

Comment: @user796837: I guess I misunderstood. Consider updating your question to clarify what you have now, how it works, and what do you want to accomplish, the way question is now written is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully updated!', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```